# Why is my loader breaking fxLayout row wrap

Tags: angular, flexbox

I have a fxLayout div with row wrap and *ngFor which is pulling an array of material cards. Recently I added a full page loader to the component and now I see that it is breaking the responsiveness of the fxLayout. Now it works only after I mouse over on element after resize.  Here is a live of the problem:
https://bellavistabulgaria.bg/test/screen-capture%20(2).gif
This is my HTML:

``````
 <div fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="loading" *ngIf="loading">
  <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</div>   
<div  *ngIf ="!loading" class="content"  [@scaleUp]="filteredArr.length">
    <div  fxLayout= "row wrap"   fxLayoutGap="10px grid">
        <div (click)="onSelect(user)" fxLayoutAlign="center"  fxFlex="25%" fxFlex.sm="50%" fxFlex.xs="100%" *ngFor="let user of filteredArr">
          <app-user-card  [user] = "user" class="user-card"></app-user-card>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

This is the CSS of the component:

````
.content{
  padding:16px;
}
.form{
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.user-card{
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 250ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.user-card:hover {
  z-index: 100;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.loading{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(143, 143, 143, 0.8);
}

`````
``````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a @HostListener like so.

```
@HostListener('window:resize')
onResize(): void {
  // executes every time the browser is resized
  // add code here to repaint / redraw the broken element
}
```

I am not familiar on how to repaint / redraw your broken element so you would need to research this.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering how to listen for window resize event in Angular, but isn't there any simplest solution for that? For now I just remove the loader element, which fixes the problem. But why is the loader creating this problem at first place, because it is not active while the list is on the screen?